# How do you compare numbers greater than 9 or negative in NASM/MASM assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm, negative-number

I'm allowed to use the C functions printf, scanf, and puts. I get a number from the user (which is easy), but I need to check to see if it's less than 0 or greater than 255? I know how to compare single digit numbers but am stuck on how to compare negative or numbers >9. would cmp eax, 0 and cmp eax,255 work?

Comment: Use scanf to get the input into a number (rather than a text representation of one). From there, just use the appropriate jmp after the comparison instructions. For some, the comparison is signed, for others, not.

Comment: The problem is a little bit unclear. Didn't you convert the (ASCII-)input to a register value e.g. with `scanf`? Please add code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It will do what you intend just
whith `cmp eax,0` instead of `jb` you should 
use `jl` (Jump if first operand is Less) cause it will be signed comparison